# How can I easily publish a ASP.NET web app using VS2010 on computer to a VM at work?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, publishing

The old school way is to copy and paste and the files.. so we don't want that anymore..

So I notice VS2010 has 'Publish'... Should I use file system and just create a shared drive on the VM and publish that way?? Should I FTP and set up FTP on the VM FTP server? Should I use web deploy?? But that seems to be made for commercial web hosting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Go with the easiest possible

If it's possible to do a *File System* deploy, then do it. Don't overcomplicate setting up additional services just to be able to deploy using something more fancy.

Comment: yes. thats how im doing it now... I was thinking maybe there was something more clever... 

next up is creating differnt web.config transformations